# What does it mean to drill holes "128mm on center"?

Tags: cabinets

I am installing cabinets in our closet. As part of the installation, I need to install door handles. The instructions say to *drill the holes 128mm on center*. My question is, 128mm from what?

The relevant instructions are seen here:
[image: Installing the handles]

Full instructions can be found in the [EasyClosets instructions](http://www.easyclosets.com/uploads/install.pdf).

Comment: Assuming you're using the same handles the instructions were written for, 128mm from **each other**. You decide where you want to position the handles. Usually they are vertical but could be at the top middle or bottom of the door. Estimate where one hole will be. Mark the other 128mm from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(What will be) The center of each hole is the measuring point, and the hole centers should be 128mm apart.